# DataGrid - Get CellValue after checking a CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

In my application I need to get ID column content of row where clicked a checkbox.
Currently I am using CheckBox_Click and datagrid_SelectionChanged but it is not working perfectly. The problem is that this handler only triggers after selection changed and it causes problems with counting properly. I've tried different handlers, but i was able to make only this one work(as it works).
What can I change in my code or which event handler I should use?

selectionchanged:

```
private void datagrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
    {
        //somecode
        try
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            if (row != null)
            {
                DataGridCell RowColumn = dataGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row).Parent as DataGridCell;
                string CellValue = ((TextBlock)RowColumn.Content).Text;
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(CellValue);
                //somecode
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
            //somecode
    } here
```

checkboxclick:

```
        private void CheckBox_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Klikniecie w checkboxa
    {
            //somecode
        if (((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked == true)
        {
            //somecode
        }
        else
        {
            //somecode
        }
            //somecode
    }
```

XAML:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True"  CanUserAddRows="false" SelectionChanged="datagrid_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup/>
            </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox Content="All" Click="CheckBoxAll_Click" x:Name="headerCheckBox" Checked="headerCheckBox_Checked"/>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chk" Margin="10 0 0 0" ClickMode="Press" Click="CheckBox_Click_1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=headerCheckBox, Mode=OneWay}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="chk_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=id}" Header="ID" Width="auto" />
                //Some columns
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Thank for you help :)

---

**EDIT:**
More code. Method where I am using my "weird" binding :D

```
        public void Aktualizuj()
    {
        try
        {
            if (aktywnatabela != "old" && aktywnatabela != "cust") { aktywnatabela = "aktywne"; }
            string selectStr = ("select * from " + aktywnatabela + " order by id asc");
            SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectStr, Start.m_dbConnection);
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            int i = myAdapter.Fill(dset);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            //MessageBox.Show(dset.GetXml().ToString());
            for (int x = 2; x <= 10; x++)
            {
                if (aktywnatabela == "cust")
                    dataGrid.Columns[x].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                else
                    dataGrid.Columns[x].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            for (int x = 11; x <= 17; x++)
            {
                if (aktywnatabela == "cust")
                    dataGrid.Columns[x].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    dataGrid.Columns[x].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT2:
I've to clarify my problem - in this way almost all is working fine - except that I've used _SelectionChanged so it's triggers only when I change the selection, when I don't CheckBox checking isn't working.

Comment: What is the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid bound to?

Comment: I am using ItemsSource in DataGrid filling method.

Comment: Of course...but what's the type of your ItemsSource collection?

Comment: Oh.. I'm not sure. Can you please tell me how do I check it?

Comment: You will have to post your code unless you think someone will be able to guess how it looks.

Comment: No problem, which part do you need? (Whole app .cs code is around 3000 lines)

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But I didn't think that this information was relevant because every other function of my app is working fine. If you need more information just tell me why and I will provide it.

Comment: I have already asked you what the ItemsSource property is bound to...

Comment: I've had edited my question, is that, what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your itemsource seems strange to me just saying but if it actually shows data in your datagrid you can do this:

First add a tag to your checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Name="chk" Margin="10 0 0 0" ClickMode="Press" Click="CheckBox_Click_1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=headerCheckBox, Mode=OneWay}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="chk_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Tag={Binding }/>
```

retrieve your tag in the click event:

```
private void CheckBox_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    // With the tag you retrieve the object of the list used in DataTemplate
    // the list is the binding you did on the itemsSource datagrid
    YourObject yourObject = (YourObject) ((CheckBox) sender).Tag;

    // Now you have retreive your entire object in the yourObject variable
    // You can retreive the specific id or other variable of your object and use it as you want
    yourObject.id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer :) I think that this solution might work but I don't understand this code completely. By `YourObject` u mean my ItemSource or DataGrid? I'm confused.

Comment: Can you share the type of your Itemssource? It must be a collection of object. I can't guess it with the information you provided

Comment: I'm not sure how do I find this but when I'm pointing on ItemsSource I see: "public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }  //    Gets or sets a collection used to generate the content of the // Returns:    A collection that is used to generate the content of the  The default is null.

Comment: I am not sure but I think I didn't define it anywhere. In my XAML I'm just using for example : <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=Data}" Header="Data" Width="auto" />(And Data is column from my SQLite Base). In .cs file I had shown all references of ItemsSource

Comment: Ok my bad I didn't see you updated your code,
I know it was strange :P your `Itemssource="{Binding}"` is useless since you do the real set in your controller with `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dset.Tables[0].DefaultView;` so if I trace it well you can change YourObject by DataTable

Comment: Thank you so much :) I need to go now, I will try it tomorrow. I hope it will work

Comment: I did a bad tracing your Itemssource is a DataView I need more time to know which list it correspond but I will do it tomorrow too :P

Comment: PS: maybe I found it you can try replace YourObject by DataRowView and then get id by doing: yourObject["id"] really hard to say for me without testing

Comment: WOW! You are amazing :) It's working now. Thank you. I am going to accept this answer + up vote it :D Have a nice day

Comment: Cool have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use a function and instert data on your datagrid when the chekbox is true something like

```
 public void FunctionName()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
           System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Your Path DataBase";
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM YourTable where Id ='" + YourID + "' ;";
        OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "YourTable");
        conn.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "YourTable";
    }
```

And you call the Function

```
private void CheckBox_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Klikniecie w checkboxa
{
        //somecode
    if (((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked == true)
    {
        FunctionName
    }
    else
    {
        //somecode
    }
        //somecode
}
```

Comment: It would be nice but my problem is i can't extract ID number in `CheckBox_Click_1`

Comment: use a listbox its better i think

Comment: my DataGrid has around 20 columns.... In many other aspects i chosen to use DataGrid